# SCCM Application Deployment - No Status or Errors

Tags: sccm

Within the Configuration Manager console I have created an application package for WMF5.1 that has a dependency on .NET Framework 4.7.2. It also supersedes WMF3.0 so there's an action included to uninstall that if present through a PowerShell script detection method. The deployment also has an OS requirement for Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.

I've deployed this to a device collection which has one Windows 2008 R2 64-bit server in it (Yes the package uses the 64-bit installer). This server has the SCCM agent installed and network connectivity is working fine.

There is no timing restriction on deployment, it's just set to "as soon as possible".

All boundries groups are configured correctly and have deployed to this server and many others in the same subnet before without issue.

Upon checking the monitoring tab for this deployment a day later, The pie chart is completely grey. I've run a summarization many times and all status tabs for this deployment just show the message "Status information is currently unavailable for this deployment"

I've checked a few server logs in the SMS_CCM\Logs folder but not seeing anything obvious. I'm assuming this hasn't reached the client yet seeing as the deployment doesn't look to have detected the device in the collection yet!?

I feel like I'm missing something here but even if my dependency or supersedence rules were wrong, surely the deployment would error rather than just show nothing!

I'm struggling to see how I can troubleshoot something that doesn't appear to have logged any activity for this action.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking further into this and even though I had no errors to go by, noticed that the application deployment was set to "Available" rather than "Required" under the "Purpose" drop-down box. Since changing that, the deployment has proceeded and is now installing as expected.